# ViewState size error when using <asp:Image> control

Tags: asp.net

I have an application where I am using an image control to create an image gallery on a product UserControl.  When I visit any product to see it's detail, it is working fine; But, there is some problem with one product.  If I visit that specific product, it throws an exception in my error log. The exception is :

> ViewState Size 5044!

The control code for the gallery is:

```
<div class="mainImage">
            <asp:Image ID="ImageControl" runat="server" BorderWidth="0" CssClass="productImage" />
            <asp:Image ID="NoIcon" runat="server" SkinID="NoIcon" Visible="false" EnableViewState="false" CssClass="productImage"/>
            <asp:Image ID="NoThumbnail" runat="server" SkinID="NoThumbnail" Visible="false" EnableViewState="false" CssClass="productImage"/>
            <asp:Image ID="NoImage" runat="server" SkinID="NoImage" Visible="false" EnableViewState="false" CssClass="productImage"/>
</div>
```

I am keep on searching but could not figure out the problem. Any one's help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide with the detailed exception that shows stack trace and inner exception. Also some code would be appreciated

Comment: here is the exception detail:

Comment: Please use preview before posting and make sure whatever you paste, comes over here.

Comment: I've fixed your post (as @Dimitri said, please use the preview below your question when posting or editing to make sure everything shows up).  Also, is that all the error said?  I don't see that "Exception" when I try to Google it.  Are you sure you're not getting an "Invalid ViewState" error?

Comment: yes.it is not an Invalid ViewState Exception.It only throws this in error log when i visit the product either with thumbnails or without thumbnails

Comment: i think something is causing the view state size to grow so much, that's why it is throwing this exception but I am unable to figure out what is that?

Comment: can any body tell me, how could I update the control to make it work with as little viewstate as possible.